# Unix wildcard expansion/ regular expression

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What will the below command do?

```
ls -l ${INPUT%.jnl}.jnl
```

`$INPUT` consists of some value.

Comment: And also please explain the command clearly.

Answer (score 1):

`${INPUT%.jnl}` strips the shortest match of `.jnl` from the back of `$INPUT`.

By then saying `${INPUT%.jnl}.jnl` it looks like a way to make `$INPUT` consist in something + `.jnl` and prevent it being two times `.jnl` at the end, if `$INPUT` already contained that value.

So `ls -l ${INPUT%.jnl}.jnl` will perform a `ls -l` in the path/name indicated by `$INPUT`, making sure it ends with `.jnl`.

See some tests regarding the `${INPUT%.jnl}` expression:

```
$ var="hello.jnl.jnlbye"
$ echo ${var%.jnl}
hello.jnl.jnlbye    # as .jnl is not present in the back, nothing gets removed

$ var="hello.jnl.jnl"
$ echo ${var%.jnl}
hello.jnl           # it removed the last .jnl
```